# R - Order/sort nested list based on mean of two elements

Tags: r, list

Example code

```
List_1 <- list(a = matrix(2,2), b = matrix(7,7), c = matrix(9,9), d = matrix(3,3))
List_2 <- list(a = matrix(7,3), b = matrix(7,7), c = matrix(7,1), d = matrix(7,9))
List_3 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))
List_4 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))
List_5 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))

List_tot <- list(List_1, List_2, List_3, List_4, List_5)

names(List_tot) <- c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5")
```

Outputting:

```
# List of 5
#  $ L1:List of 4
#   ..$ a: num [1:2, 1] 2 2
#   ..$ b: num [1:7, 1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
#   ..$ c: num [1:9, 1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
#   ..$ d: num [1:3, 1] 3 3 3
#  $ L2:List of 4
#   ..$ a: num [1:3, 1] 7 7 7
#   ..$ b: num [1:7, 1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
#   ..$ c: num [1, 1] 7
#   ..$ d: num [1:9, 1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
...
```

I want to sort L1, L2, L3... by first the mean of column n in 'c', then second by the mean of column n in 'a'. So I will get the L with highest mean of 'c' and highest mean of 'a' first. Then, the L with highest mean of 'c' and second highest mean of 'a'...etc

This example shows one-column matrix, but assume there are multi columns in each list

My attempt is by using `lapply` and `with(order`, but I can't get any orders set. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the column 'c', get the `mean` and `order`

```
i1 <- order(-sapply(List_tot[c("L1", "L2", "L3")], function(x) mean(x[['c']])))
i2 <-  order(-sapply(List_tot[c("L4", "L4")], function(x) mean(x[['a']])))
List_tot[c(i1, i2 + length(i1))]
```